# What is the latest Eclipse version on which the TFS plugin can run?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, tfs

I have the TFS plugin running in Eclipse 3.8.
Now planning to upgrade eclipse to the latest, but expecting TFS plugin issues...
what is the latest eclipse version in which the TFS plugin has been running successfully?

Answer (score 0):

From the [system requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727) as of today:

> Integrated development environment (IDE) requirements:
>   IDEs that are based on Eclipse 3.5 to 4.5 on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris, AIX, or HP-UX.